# How do I avoid duplicate DLL conflicts with native NuGet packages?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, nuget

We are building a Windows Store App in VS2012 that depends on a C# (main UI) project, several C++ projects (for supporting code), and an external proprietary library.  The external library is delivered to us as a DLL + header files, which we have put into a native [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) package using [AutoPackage](http://coapp.org/tutorials/building-a-package.html).

Three of the C++ projects make calls to the external library.  I can install the external library package (from GUI or command line) for each of the three projects, and can compile and build the entire solution with no complaints from Visual Studio.  However, if I exit Visual Studio and then re-open the solution, or if I try to unload and reload the projects including the package, Visual Studio refuses to load two of the projects that import the NuGet package.  It says:

```
foo.vcxproj : error  : The item "..\..\..\..\abc\packages\Bar.WinRT.redist.1.2.3.4\build\native\bin\Win32\bar.dll" already exists under the filter "".
```

where `Bar.WinRT.redist.1.2.3.4` is the external library package containing `bar.dll`, and `foo` is the project trying to include the package.  (File names edited for simplicity, and project privacy.)

The only way I can get either of the affect projects to load again is to manually delete the import of `Bar.WinRT.redist` from `foo.vcxproj` and reload the project.  After reloading the project, I can re-install `Bar.WinRT.redist` either from the package manager command line or the Manage NuGet Packages dialog.

AutoPackage automatically builds "Bar.WinRT" and "Bar.WinRT.redist" from the header files and dll, respectively.  Only the project used to build the final .exe needs the "redist" package, but it gets pulled in automatically because AutoPackage makes the non-redist package (containing the header files) depend on the redist package.

What is the best way to include the external package and still have projects load correctly (and have precisely one copy of the DLL wind up in the build output with the .exe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem appears to be that the projects that failed to load had an AppContainerApplication property setting in their project file, and did not have a WindowsAppContainer property setting.

I removed the AppContainerSetting property by manually editing the project XML file.  Then I

1. Enabled the `Windows Store App Support` on the General properties page,
2. Set the `Consume Windows Runtime Extension` option to `Yes (/ZW)` on the C/C++ All Options page, and
3. Set the `Enable Minimal Rebuild` to `No (/Gm-)`, also on the C/C++ All Options page.

It is not clear how the project was loading prior to adding the NuGet package, but updating the settings seems to have fixed the issue.